# Calculating a new column with numpy using for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, multiple-columns

i have a Dataset called np_charge in numpy with a size of (1430, 258).
My idea is to create a new column where the first row contains the output of the equation

first row:    np_charge[-1][1]-np_charge[0][1]

second row:   np_charge[-1][1]-np_charge[1][1] 
.
.
.

last row: np_charge[-1][1]-np_charge[1429][1]

I tried to find solutions in the internet but couldn't find any. My solution looks like this:

```
e=[]

n_rows=np_charge.shape[0]-1

for i in range(n_rows):
    e[i]=(np_charge[-1][1]-np_charge[i][1])
```

But I get this error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-988-9463a5cb0618> in <module>()
 15 
 16 for i in range(n_rows):
---> 17     e[i]=np_charge[-1][1]-np_charge[i][1]
 18 
 19 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 0):

For loop is not recommanded. Numpy is optimized to do array-wise operations. A quick example:

```
L = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(20, 10))
new = L[-1][1]-L[:][1]
Out[61]: array([-3,  0, -3,  0,  1, -1,  0,  1, -3, -2])
```

So in your case, the new column would be the same but with `np_charge` instead of `L`.

N.B: Your error comes from the fact that you do not use the `append()` method of your list `e`. First iteration, you look for the index 0 in the list `[]`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified by you in one of your comments. Creating MVE

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import random
a=np.array([datetime.now()-relativedelta(months=random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(10)])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
 array([datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000),
           datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 12, 9, 0, 31, 696000)], dtype=object)
```

tn I am assuming last index of the array. Therefore

```
result=a[len(a)-1]-a

[datetime.timedelta(488),
 datetime.timedelta(-943),
 datetime.timedelta(671),
 datetime.timedelta(1767),
 datetime.timedelta(123),
 datetime.timedelta(1553),
 datetime.timedelta(-29),
 datetime.timedelta(-608),
 datetime.timedelta(2071),
 datetime.timedelta(0)]
```